# Corrupted form in the solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a new problem today. After loading the project, I encountered the destruction of the original form of the program. This project is designed in the language of VB.NET. It is clear in the image below that after loading the form the form window will be displayed as binary code. Help me please.
With respect
Hamed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTZ9O.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDjaO.png)

Comment: The file shown in VS is all nulls or empty. Can you confirm that's the case by trying to look at the file outside of VS (i.e. Windows Explorer)? If so, not much we can do to help. Hopefully you have a backup copy or something in source control.